# Dice Class sides from 3-100

Tags: validation, class

Say I have a class called Dice  written in java

```
//instance variables

private int numSides;

//Class variables

public final int MIN_VALUE = 3;

public final int MAX_VALUE = 100;

//construct die

public Dice(int sides){

 setSides(a);

}


//set sides

public void setSides(int a){

numSides = a;

}
```

Now assume I have a main and I create a die

```
Dice a = new Dice(200);
```

Here is my question 
should the method `setSides` check for the bounds and `System.out.println("too large")/"too small"`
or
should I change the method to a String make the same test and return either null or "too large"/"too small"
or should I let the user call `Dice.MIN_VALUE` and `Dice.MAX_VALUE` in the main and not allow the user to type in a value smaller or greater or give an error if they do?

I know i could change the method to

```
public void setSides(int a) {

numSides = Math.max(MIN_VALUE, a);
numSides = Math.min(MAX_VALUE, a);

}
```

and avoid the error but the user would never know

ultimately my question is when we are interacting with the user who (meaning which class) should do the data validation?

Comment: What language?  Looks like Java....

Comment: Provide a default value; report, then ignore invalid new values.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the setSides() method check for errors.

Something like

```
public Dice(int size)
{
    numSides = setSides(size)
}

public void setSides(int a){
    int sizeReturned = 0;
    if (a <= MAX_VALUE && a >= MIN_VALUE)
        sizeReturned  = a;
    else if (a > MAX_VALUE){
            // print error message
        sizeReturned  = MAX_VALUE;}
    else if (a < MIN_VALUE){
            // print error message
        sizeReturned  = MIN_VALUE;}
    else{//something weird has happened.
    }
    return sizeReturned;
}
```

You can print error messages letting the user know that they went out of bounds. Here, I programmed that if they do go out of bounds, it will automatically take the upper or lower bounds as the value.

In this example, the dice class can take care of the data validation through the setSides() method. Remember, every class that is an extension of this class will inherit the property.